# Generic template for nested abstract base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class, generic-programming

I am attempting to make a class that can be used to template other classes. Maybe I'm looking for the wrong key words. Essentially I would like `PrimaryClass` and class `A` to be pure virtual. `DerivedClass` and `C` are derived from their respective classes. **The issue is that by calling the inherited class: `C` in `DerivedClass` I am not overriding the pure virtual `PrimaryClass`**. I'm aware of this but I do not know how to fix it.

I was under the impression that since `C` is derived from `A` it would work. 
If I change `C` in

```
virtual void DoFunThings ( C<T>* d ) {}
```

to `A` it works but the point of this is to allow *differently derived versions of `A` to be used.*

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:  
    virtual void FunThings ( const A<T> &orig, A<T>* new_one ) = 0;   
    T thing{};
};


template <class T>
class C: public A < T >
{
public:
    virtual void FunThings ( const C<T> &orig, C<T>* new_one ) {}

};


template <class T>
class PrimaryClass
{
public:    
    virtual void DoFunThings ( A<T>* d ) = 0;
};



template<class T>
class DerivedClass: public PrimaryClass<T>
{
public:
    virtual void DoFunThings ( C<T>* d ) {}
};


int main ()
{
    DerivedClass<int> derived;

    return 0;
}
```

If it is not possible to do it this way how can one go about making generic object oriented code with my desired functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are not overriding `DoFunThings` of `PrimaryClass` in `DerivedClass`.  You are merely *overloading* it.  To override it they have to have the same signature.  You can easily detect this mistake in C++11 by using the `override` keyword.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:  
    virtual void FunThings ( const A<T> &orig, A<T>* new_one ) = 0;   
    T thing{};
};

template <class T>
class C: public A < T >
{
public:
    virtual void FunThings ( const C<T> &orig, C<T>* new_one ) {}
};

template <class T>
class PrimaryClass
{
public:    
    virtual void DoFunThings ( A<T>* d ) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class DerivedClass: public PrimaryClass<T>
{
public:
    virtual void DoFunThings ( C<T>* d ) override {}
};

int main ()
{
    DerivedClass<int> derived;
}
```

Now the compiler (in my case Clang) will emit an error:

```
test.cpp:27:18: error: 'DoFunThings' marked 'override' but does not override any
      member functions
    virtual void DoFunThings ( C<T>* d ) override {}
```

Comment: I stated I was aware of the override issue and needed a solution to utilize derivations of A.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to give PrimaryClass and DerivedClass templates not of the unique data type for A & C (int in the question) but for the classes A & C.

```
template <class D>
class PrimaryClass
{
public:

    virtual void DoFunThings ( D* d ) = 0;
};



template<class D>
class DerivedClass: public PrimaryClass<D>
{
public:
    virtual void DoFunThings ( D* d ) {}
};


int main ()
{
    DerivedClass<C<int>> derived;

    return 0;
}
```

I was under the faulty assumption that since C was derived from A it could be used. Not sure where I read/misunderstood it but it lead to a lot of wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of machinery and templates to simulate a virtual function template somehow and get something quite close to what you are looking for (probably).
As an example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

template <class T>
class A {};

template <class T>
class B: public A < T > {};

template <class T>
class C: public A < T > {};

template <class>
class PrimaryClass;

template <typename T, template<typename> class U>
class PrimaryClass<U<T>>
{
    template<typename D, typename Z = U<T>>
    auto DoFunThings(int, D *d)
    -> decltype(static_cast<Z*>(this)->DoFunThingsOverride(d)) {
        return static_cast<Z*>(this)->DoFunThingsOverride(d);
    }

    void DoFunThings(char, A<T> *) {
        // do whatever you want if
        // derived class has not a
        // proper specialization
        std::cout << "PrimaryClass::DoFunThings" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    template<typename D>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A<T>, D>::value, void>
    DoFunThings ( D* d ) {
        DoFunThings(0, d);
    }
};

template<class T>
class DerivedClass: public PrimaryClass<DerivedClass<T>>
{
public:
    void DoFunThingsOverride ( C<T>* ) {
        std::cout << "DerivedClass::DoFunThings" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main ()
{
    DerivedClass<int> derived;
    B<int> b;
    C<int> c;

    derived.DoFunThings(&b);
    derived.DoFunThings(&c);

    return 0;
}
```

See it in [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aK7E2ULvJVNiVrYT).